# Сервис + передача видео

Tags: c#, видео, wcf, streaming

Пытаюсь написать передачу видео с камеры, использую wcf. Видео шлётся только с одного компьютера другому, причём компьютер тут как реальная физическая сущность.

Суть проблемы. Есть компьютер 1 и компьтер 2. На 1-ом компьютере запустил сервис. Скопировал клиентскую часть на обе машины, т.е. исполняемые экземпляры полностью идентичны. При этом видео шлётся только с 1-го компьютера на 2-ой. Наоборот по какой-то причине не работает.

Я предположил, что может быть это как-то связано с тем, где запущен сервис, но - нет. Если сервис активировать на машине 2, то видео всё равно отсылается с 1-ой на 2-ую, но никогда наоборот. Прошу помочь разобраться, что не так.

Проект на [гитхабе](https://github.com/jacky22/Chat).

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IChatService))]
    public interface IChatService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Join(string memberName);
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Leave(string memberName);
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendMessage(string memberName, string message);
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Call(string memberName, byte[] message);
    }

    public interface IChatChannel : IChatService, IClientChannel
    {
    }

    public partial class ChatClient : Form, IChatService
    {
        private delegate void UserJoined(string name);
        private delegate void UserSendMessage(string name, string message);
        private delegate void UserCall(string name, byte[] message);
        private delegate void UserLeft(string name);

        private static event UserJoined NewJoin;
        private static event UserSendMessage MessageSent;
        private static event UserCall userCall;
        private static event UserLeft RemoveUser;private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text.Trim()))
            {
                try
                {
                    NewJoin += new UserJoined(ChatClient_NewJoin);
                    MessageSent += new UserSendMessage(ChatClient_MessageSent);
                    RemoveUser += new UserLeft(ChatClient_RemoveUser);
                    userCall += new UserCall(ChatClient_Call);
                    channel = null;
                    this.userName = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
                    InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(
                        new ChatClient(txtUserName.Text.Trim()));
                    factory =
                        new DuplexChannelFactory<IChatChannel>(context, "ChatEndPoint");
                    channel = factory.CreateChannel();
                    IOnlineStatus status = channel.GetProperty<IOnlineStatus>();
                    status.Offline += new EventHandler(Offline);
                    status.Online += new EventHandler(Online);                    
                    channel.Open();                    
                    channel.Join(this.userName);
                    grpMessageWindow.Enabled = true;
                    grpUserList.Enabled = true;                    
                    grpUserCredentials.Enabled = false;                    
                    this.AcceptButton = btnSend;
                    rtbMessages.AppendText("*****************************WEL-COME to Chat Application*****************************\r\n");
                    txtSendMessage.Select();
                    txtSendMessage.Focus();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        void ChatClient_Call(string name, byte[] message)
        {
            try
            {
                if (name == "1")
                {
                    EncodingImage enc = new EncodingImage();
                    var result = enc.EncodingImageForRecievedBuffer(message);
                    pictureBox1.Image = result;
                }
                else
                {
                    EncodingImage enc = new EncodingImage();
                    var result = enc.EncodingImageForRecievedBuffer(message);
                    pictureBox2.Image = result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void Call(string memberName, byte[] message)
        {
            if (MessageSent != null)
            {
                userCall(memberName, message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isStop = false;
            Thread t1 = new Thread(start);
            t1.Start();
        }

        private void start()
        {
            while (!isStop)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                CodingImage image = new CodingImage();
                byte[] bytes = image.CodingImages(video);
                channel.Call(this.userName, bytes);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Когда начинаю шарить видео с вебки(со 2го компьютера), на 1ой машине постоянно вызывается метод void Online(object sender, EventArgs e), а должен void ChatClient_Call(string name, byte[] message).
Когда начинаю отправку с 1го на 2ой- все хорошо. Видео передается и отображается.

Comment: А вы не могли бы добавить логирование? Было бы понятно, вызывается ли отправляющий метод на сервере, и принимающий метод на клиенте. (И если вас не затруднит, почему бы не убрать нерелевантный код из примера? UI-операции и функциональность чата ведь не являются темой вопроса?)

Comment: Да, отправляющий метод вызывается. Вы правы, поэтому приложил ссылку на гитхаб(не был уверен, что может понадобиться)
https://github.com/jacky22/Chat/blob/master/ChatClient/ChatClient.cs

Comment: Окей, а принимающий метод вызывается?

Comment: нет, в том и дело. Вместо принимающего вызывается, как я уже писал, void Online(object sender, EventArgs e)
но почему я так и не понял(
предполагаю какая-то проблема с сервисом, но какая..?